# Adding data points to existing graph with Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, graph, dygraphs

I have an existing graph created with [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) based on a JavaScript array. I also have a process that generates new values, say once per second, as JavaScript array.

Is it possible to add the new values to the existing graph? I'd like to avoid redrawing the whole graph each time a new value is created.

```
var data = [[1,99,42],[2,98,52]]
var graph = new Dygraph(element, data, {});
// now graph is created and visible

// how to add newPoint to existing graph?
var newPoint = [3,100,20];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `file` for all kinds of data, not just for CSV files.

```js
data.push(newPoint);
graph.updateOptions({file: data});
```